# Hibernate one-to-many map without foreign key

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Hi I have a class that contains a map :

```
private Map<class2, List<Integer>> abc;
```

Now in my implementation I get the following tables:

```
class 1:
+------+-----+
| Date | abc |
+------+-----+

class 2:
+----+------+------+
| ID | Name | Date |
+----+------+------+
```

But I dont want a foreign key in class 2 I want a 3rd table that would look like this:

```
class 1:
+------+-----+
| Date | abc |
+------+-----+

class 2:
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+

class1+2
+-------+----+
| Date  | id |
+-------+----+
| 17.02 |  1 |
| 17.02 |  2 |
| 18.02 |  1 |
+-------+----+
```

Now the thing is this should be a one-to-many relation and not a many-to-many.
Can someone post a compilable xml mapping for my problem e.g. something like:

```
<map name="abc" table="MEAL_DAY" lazy="true" access="field">
        <key>
            <column name="DATE" />
        </key>
        .....
<one-to-many ...
    </map>
```

I would be very grateful. Thanks